# Static Library with _penter definition (/Gh) not recognized by project configuration type Dynamic Library dll

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, profiling, hook, compiler-options

I have added the link of two projects, exactly same dummy code but different project types, first one is "Application (.exe)" {[link to download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_LJ7JfgiyascUZDckJUNjNSWFk)} and the second one is "Dynamic Library (dll)" {[link to download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_LJ7JfgiyasRzFjNW1ZSTBZRTQ)}. I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, with the [/Gh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) compiler option for both projects. There is another project included in both solutions that is NOT compiled with /Gh option and has implementation of _penter hook function. Strangely, the first project compiles fine and _penter is reached and functions properly (prints on console). The second one (dll) is throwing compilation error of "LNK2019  unresolved external symbol __penter referenced in function _DllMain@12" when compiled with /Gh switch. Also, I have tried with c and c++ code in both solutions, first one works with both and second works with none.

**Configuration of Library Project**
[image: Configuration of Library Project]

Just for reference, code content is pasted below.

**Dll Project -- dllmain.c**

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Profile\Profile.h"

int a = 7;
char ch = 'a';

char y(char c) {
    return c + 1;
}
int xx2(int c, int d) {
    y(ch++); return c + 3;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                    LPVOID lpReserved
                    )
{


    a = xx2(5, 100);
    a = xx2(70, 200);
    a = xx2(150, 300);
    ch = y(ch);
    ch = y(ch);
    ch = y(ch);

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**Exe Project -- sample.c**

```
// Sample.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Profile\Profile.h"

int a = 7;
char ch = 'a';

char y(char c) { 
    printf("%c", c); return c + 1; 
}
int xx2(int c, int d) { 
    printf("%d", c); y(ch++); return c + 3; 
}

int main() {
    //PassSomething(xx2, "int xx2(int c, int d)\0");
    a = xx2(5, 100);
    a = xx2(70, 200);
    a = xx2(150, 300);
    ch = y(ch);
    ch = y(ch);
    ch = y(ch);
}
```

**Included Profiler Project - header profile.h**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <tchar.h>

typedef struct
{
    const void  * function;     // function address
    const TCHAR * parameter;    // formatting string for parameter decoding, '?' for class method
    const TCHAR * returnval;    // formatting string for return value decoding,
}   Signature;

typedef struct 
{   
    void * Pointer;
    char  Name[100];
    char  Parameters[20][100];
    char  ReturnType[20];
}   Function;
```

**Included Profiler Project - code profile.cpp**

```
#define STRICT

#include "profile.h"

#define MAX_DEPTH 512           // good enough for 512 levels of nesting

void * Stack[MAX_DEPTH * 2];    // NOT multi-thread safe
int    SP = 0;
int    depth = 0;



void _stdcall ExitFunc(unsigned * pStack)
{
    TCHAR       temp[MAX_PATH];
    Signature * pSig;

    OutputDebugString("Exit \n");

    SP--;
    pSig = (Signature *)Stack[SP];

    SP--;
    pStack[0] = (unsigned)Stack[SP]; // change return address to point to original caller
}

extern "C" __declspec(naked) void __cdecl _pexit()
{
    _asm
    {
        push   eax        // function return value and placehold for return to original caller
        pushad            // save all general purpose registers 
        mov    eax, esp   // current stack pointer  
        add    eax, 32    // stack pointer before pushad
        push   eax        // push pointer to where EAX is saved as parameter to ExitFunc

        call   ExitFunc

        popad             // restore general registers
        ret               // return to original caller  
    }
}

void _stdcall EnterFunc(unsigned * pStack)
{

    char       temp[MAX_PATH];
    Signature * pSig;
    void      * pCaller;
    pCaller = (void *)(pStack[0] - 5); // the instruction for calling _penter is 5 bytes long
    pSig = NULL;//FuncTable;

    OutputDebugString("Entered \n");

    Stack[SP++] = (void *)pStack[1]; // save return address to original caller
    Stack[SP++] = pSig;               // save functions signature

    pStack[1] = (unsigned)_pexit;  // HACK stack to link to _pexit  

    depth++;
}

void _stdcall EnterFunc0(unsigned * pStack)
{
    EnterFunc(pStack);                                  // process the call
}

extern "C" __declspec(naked) void __cdecl _penter()
{
    _asm
    {
        pushad              // save all general purpose registers
        mov    eax, esp     // current stack pointer
        add    eax, 32      // stack pointer before pushad
        push   eax          // push pointer to return address as parameter to EnterFunc0

        call   EnterFunc0

        popad               // restore general purpose registers
        ret                 // start executing original function
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Complete solution links are provided inline.

Comment: My guess is that when you created your ""Dynamic Library" project, it inadvertently targets.Net, instead of unmanaged code?

Comment: I can try changing that, can you tell how to?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of project properties page in the description. I am fairly new to c/c++ development after 6 years of c# so expect some noobness.